# WixCode controlling view of element on mobile / desktop

Tags: velo

I'm learning the new [Wix Code](https://www.wix.com/code/home) online development IDE and want to understand how to control the visibility of an item on mobile or desktop. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to hide things from mobile, there's an easier way to do it (go to the mobile editor and click the element's hide button).

But assuming you're asking about WixCode because you need custom behavior:

Check out the formFactor API
https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-window.html#formFactor
And the properties panel
https://support.wix.com/en/article/working-with-the-properties-panel-6441151

The properties panel is where you'll set the element's default visibility.
Then check the formFactor using that API above
And finally use $w('#elementname).show() or hide() to change its visibility.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options -

If you only want to control what appears on mobile vs desktop, you have a toggle to hide elements on mobile.

If you want to change dynamically visibility of elements on each or both, use the formFactor and hide/show/collapse/expand APIs.

For instance, on a button click you may want to show element1 on desktop and element 2 on mobile. The code will look something like the following -

```
import wixWindow from 'wix-window';

export function button1_onClick() {
  if (wixWindow.formFactor === 'Mobile') {
    $w('#element2').show();
  }
  else {
    $w('#element1').show();
  }
}
```